# New to Maven where is my Spring jars

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am new to maven and I am trying to follow this example but after

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

should I see my Spring jars so where?

http://saiboten.com/blog/2011/03/basic-spring-30-eclipse-project-with-maven-3/

Comment: Maven keeps its jars in your local repository, normally in your home directory under `$HOME/.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the maven Eclipse project from the maven pom is not enough. This only generates the eclipse project files. You also need to activate/install a [maven plugin into Eclipse](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html).

Answer (score 0):

By running
`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`,

the jars will be in project's `target/dependency/` folder.

[Getting Started with Maven and Spring](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/01/17/green-beans-getting-started-with-maven-and-spring/)